# Best method for a Semaphore in a MapViewOfFile - C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Hello Users of StackOverflow.
I have been working with the MapViewOfFile from the Win32 API in C++, I'm a newbie on it, but I have been trying to create a semaphore for a mapview file, so one instance can't copy to it unless the other instance has already  copied to it and the main instance have read it.

The idea I got was creating different methods to do it, but I need to know the best way to do it.
**1)** Using the while loop for wait the mapviewfile to be empty.
I tried to do the following:

```
mapViewFile = (LPTSTR) MapViewOfFile(mapView,
FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,0,0,SH_MAX_MEMORY);

if(mapViewFile!=NULL){

// Wait for the mapviewfile to be empty.
while(mapViewFile!=""); // This while is only for delay the operation and wait for the mapviewfile it's empty, we don't need any action in this while.
CopyMemory((PVOID)mapViewFile,defaultalloc,(_tcslen(defaultalloc) * sizeof(TCHAR)));
UnmapViewOfFile(mapViewFile);
}

CloseHandle(mapView);
```

So, when the mapviewfile it's empty, the while gets skipped and the "secondary" instance copies into it, then the main instance reads it and empty the mapviewfile, this generates a semaphore.

**2)** Using a mutex
The other way, it's to use the mutex from the Win32 Api with the `CreateMutex`
I haven't worked with this yet, but I think I can do with this what I want to do.

---

So, My questions are the following:

1. Which way it's the best to do what I want to do? (Explained in the 1 paragraph)
2. A mapviewfile is not problematic doing this? (Remember I want to communicate two or more instances with a main instance).

Those are the questions, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to synchronize access to a shared resource. The way to do that is to use a synchronization object. Which means to use a mutex.

Using a mutex means that you can do idle waiting rather than a busy loop. And you also don't need to concern yourself with the compiler optimising away the read of `mapViewFile` in the `while` loop. And if you have multiple processes writing then you've got a data race that you cannot resolve without a mutex or equivalent. Your first option can never work in that scenario.

Incidentally you would need to use `strcmp` in the `while` loop test. That's because `mapViewFile!=""` always evaluates true.

Comment: That will be a good way, I tried to work with it... I don't know if you can put an example. The main instance should get access to that mutex whatever if it's locked or unlocked. For example, the instance #2 copies information and it finishes copying the information, but the main instance has not read it yet, so the #3 can't copy information unless the main instance has read it. What I have in mind, is that the #2 locks the mutex and the main instance unlocks it, am I wrong?

Comment: Well, that's a different question. And to be quite honest, it's not appropriate for Stack Overflow. There are already millions of examples of how to use a mutex. Find one, with a websearch, try it, and if you have specific problems, then that can be a further question.

Comment: Thanks, well, what I wanted with this question, is to know which was the best way, and it's now answered. I'll keep looking and I'll edit the question with the solution.

Comment: You don't need to edit the question. It's just fine as it is. Adding a solution to the question just defeats the SO question and answer format. Plus, there are already enough examples of using mutexes. It's really not that hard! Create it with `CreateMutex`. Give it a name. Other processes can call `CreateMutex` or `OpenMutex` to get hold it the same mutex`. Acquire the lock with `WaitForSingleObject`. Release the lock with a call to `ReleaseMutex`. When you have finished with the handle, call `CloseHandle`.

Comment: Ok my friend. Thanks for the tip and for your help. Marking your answer as 'accepted answer'